# Build error on Ionic Pro build process

Tags: ionic-framework

I am batting to get a successful build on IonicJs when I push my code up to the Ionic Git remote.

My application sits in a subfolder on the root directory of my repository. At first when I execute “npm run build” on the root the build process was telling me it could not find my package.json file. After reading the ionic docs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/basics/concepts/customizing-builds.html) I noticed that in the case of an app being in a sub folder you need to place another package.json file in the root of your repository. I did this and the above error was solved and the build process worked on my local machine. But when I push the changes up to the Ionic Js for building it tells me that its “Missing ionic.config.json in app.”

Here is the package.json file I placed in the root of my repository.

```
{
  "author": "",
  "name": "io.cordova.myappe070fb",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "cd App && npm install",
    "build": "cd App && .\\node_modules\\.bin\\ionic-app-scripts build --prod"

  }
}
```

`

My questions:

1. Is there a way to configure the package.json file in the root of the repository so that when Ionic runs “npm run build” it will build based on the package.json file in the App folder.
2. How do I solve the problem regarding the missing ionic.config.json error that is being generated by ionic.

Kind regards
Andrew